# C# Xaml Project FN=F7

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm currently building a C# Music Player Application and the .xaml file used to create buttons etc.

I have a `KeyboardAccelerator` where I have set it to `F7`, which works but when I try to do `Fn+F7` inside or outside of the app it doesn't work.

I was wondering if this would be possible or not, if it is possible how would I be able to do it?

```
<AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind RW}" Icon="Previous" LabelPosition="Collapsed" Label="Previous">

    <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>

        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Menu" Key="F7" />

    </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>

</AppBarButton>
```

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: It's not clear from this post exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so my application accepts FN+F7 to pause songs aswell as FN+F8 and FN+F6 but it only accepts F7 in the application

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to make that clear. The sentence "But when I try to do Fn+F7 outside of the app or inside the app" ends in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: Edited, any ideas on how to solve this issue as I'm stuck on it.